# $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ Diffeomorphism with special property

Tags: differential-geometry

$\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a diffeomorphism with the following property

$a\in\mathbb{R},|a|<\frac{1}{10}$

(i)$\phi(a)=0$

(ii) $\phi(x)=x$ when $|x|>1$

and how to generalize that in $\mathbb{R}^n$

please help.

Comment: what is $\phi$ ?

Comment: Maybe try something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's generalize: Suppose $a\in B_{\frac{1}{10}}(0)$; the idea is to construct a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that in a neighbourhood which contains $0$, $a$ and is contained in $B_1(0)$, the field points in the "direction" of the vector $-a$ with positive velocity, and in the complement, the field is zero.

If we construct this field in such a way that it is Lipschitz, then we know that there exist a flow associated to the field, i.e. if the field is given by $x'(t)=f(x(t))$ with $x(0)=a$, where $f$ is Lipschitz, then there exist a function $F$ depending on $t$ and $a$, satisfying $$\frac{\partial F(a,t)}{\partial t}=f(F(a,t))$$

Moreover, this functions has some good properties:

I- It is $C^1$,

II- $F(a,0)=a$,

III- $F(a,s+t)=F(F(a,t),s)$

IV- For each fixed $t$, $F(a,t):\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is an diffeomorphism

Case 1: $\mathbb{R}$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be a small number and construct an $C^1$ function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$, such that $g(t)=1$ if $t\in [0,a]$; $0\leq g(t)\leq 1$ if $t\in (-\epsilon,0)\cup (a,a+\epsilon)$ and $g(t)=0$ on the rest. Consider the vector field $$x'(t)=-g(t),\ x(0)=b$$

Let $F(b,t)$ be the flow associated with this vector field. Note that for $b\in [0,a]$ and $t\in [0,b]$ your flow is defined by $F(b,t)=b-t$. This implies that if $b=a$, then $F(a,a)=0$. Because $F(b,a)$ (b varying) is an diffeomorphism and $F(b,a)=b$ for $b$ in the set where $g$ is zero, you can conclude.

Case 2: $\mathbb{R}^n$

Try to do this case.

Comment: I have voted to close two questions that are almost identical to this. Since this will attract more readers to this page, would you care to add more details to Case 2? Also, there is [a new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2268695/constructing-diffeomorphism-of-rn) that adds one requirement, maybe you have an idea about it?